Clojure reduce not producing expected results
Why does the first reduce not work but the second does? The order of the comparisons should be the same...
(reduce (fn [{:keys [minimum maximum]} new-number]
          {:minimum (if (and minimum (< new-number minimum))
                      new-number
                      minimum)
           :maximum (if (and maximum (> new-number maximum))
                      new-number
                      maximum)})
        {}
        [5 23 5004 845 22])

(reduce (fn [{:keys [minimum maximum]} new-number]
          {:minimum (if (and minimum (> new-number minimum))
                      minimum
                      new-number)
           :maximum (if (and maximum (< new-number maximum))
                      maximum
                      new-number)})
        {}          ;; <---- The new argument!
        [5 23 5004 845 22])

The first reduce returns nil as the values to the keys; the second reduce works as expected. Why?

@JaredSmith The comparisons are reversed and so are the then and else clauses. The point is to keep the numeric "polarity" the same, while reversing which is considered the default when the accumulator is nil.

@amalloy you're right, close-vote retracted.

I'm going to assume that you intended to leave off the {} argument to the first reduce call, as the comment suggests.
Clojure's reduce has two different arities you can use. The first takes 2 arguments the function f to call and the coll to iterate over. And the second takes f, init (an initial value), and coll.
If init is not provided, then reduce will take the first element of the collection and treat it as the accumulator, and the iterate over the rest of the collection. Because you didn't provide an initial value to reduce in the first case, your f is called with 5 as the initial accumulator value and 23 and the new-number.
Your f will try to destructure the provided 5 which in turn creates nils and thus pollutes your data. Rewriting your first reduce with some logging, you can see the error immediately:
(reduce (fn [accumulator new-number]
          (println :acc accumulator :new-num new-number)
          (let [{:keys [minimum maximum]} accumulator]
            (println :minimum minimum :maximum maximum)
            {:minimum (if (and minimum (< new-number minimum))
                        new-number
                        minimum)
             :maximum (if (and maximum (> new-number maximum))
                        new-number
                        maximum)}))
        [5 23 5004 845 22])
;; prints
:acc 5 :new-num 23
:minimum nil :maximum nil
:acc {:minimum nil, :maximum nil} :new-num 5004
:minimum nil :maximum nil
:acc {:minimum nil, :maximum nil} :new-num 845
:minimum nil :maximum nil
:acc {:minimum nil, :maximum nil} :new-num 22
:minimum nil :maximum nil
{:minimum nil, :maximum nil}

By supplying the {}, then the accumulator will be {} and thus will work correctly.
Or at least, it would if you had written the logic correctly. The second one works as anticipated, both because of the inclusion of the empty map as initial argument, and the correct logic of finding minimum and maximum.

irrelevant to the question as stated.
to avoid this kind of issues, you could employ something like this:
(reduce (fn [acc new-number]
          (->> acc
               (merge-with min {:minimum new-number})
               (merge-with max {:maximum new-number})))
        {}
        [5 23 5004 845 22])

or
(reduce (fn [acc new-number]
          (-> acc
              (update :minimum min new-number)
              (update :maximum max new-number)))
        {:minimum ##Inf :maximum ##-Inf}
        [5 23 5004 845 22])


You might consider your answer irrelevant to the OP, but I find it quite useful. Antonio will benefit from studying these! The update variant in particular showcases Clojure at its most clear, clean, concise and powerful.

Whether you pass in an init-value or not in your first example makes not
difference, because your if expressions are written so that a missing
initial value for either minimum or maximum propagates itself
through the whole iteration.
In the first iteration the minimum/maximum are nil, because they
can not be de-structured from the first value or the init-value.
Then the if is basically (if minimum _ minimum); as in minimum is
nil, the rest of the and is not relevant so new-number never has
a chance to be relevant.
Turning things around in your second example means, that a missing value
turns into the first new-value; so everything works fine from here.
Whether providing the init-value for the reduce now makes a difference
in the result.  If you run the reduce without the init-value, the
first call to your fn there is basically (reducing-fn 5 23); 5 is
no map, so you de-structure nil out of it - the iterations work, but
the actual minimum has vanished, hence the wrong result of a minimum
with 22 instead.

Your initial value in both cases is an empty map, where :minimum and :maximum are both nil.
The minimum or maximum between nil and any other number is always that other number (depending on your use case).
Let's look at the :minimum and :maximum conditions in isolation.
Minimum
In both cases when we evaluate (min-1 nil 5) or (min-2 nil 5), minimum is nil (or falsy). The condition immediately evaluates to false and we get the else condition. We never evaluate (< new-number minimum) or (> new-number minimum) because of the short-circuit evaluation of and.
In the first case, the else condition is minimum, which is nil, so we constantly get nil as our :minimum.
In the second case, the else condition is new-number, which is 5. So we get some value back as our :minimum.
(defn min-1 [minimum new-number]
  (if (and minimum (< new-number minimum))
    new-number
    minimum))

(defn min-2 [minimum new-number]
  (if (and minimum (> new-number minimum))
    minimum
    new-number))

Maximum
We see the same thing in the maximum functions as we did with minimum.
When we evaluate (max-1 nil 5) or (max-2 nil 5), maximum is nil (falsy) and we get the else condition.
In the first case, the else condition is maximum, which is nil.
In the second case, the else condition is new-number, which is 5.
(defn max-1 [maximum new-number]
  (if (and maximum (> new-number maximum))
    new-number
    maximum))

(defn max-2 [maximum new-number]
  (if (and maximum (< new-number maximum))
    maximum
    new-number))


I'll just explain why the bad ones fail. I'm sure you'll then be able to see why the good ones work.
For any function g and sequence s. the expression ...
(reduce
  (fn [m n] (and m (g m n)))
  nil
  s)

... evaluates to nil. For example, ...
(reduce
  (fn [m n] (and m (+ m n)))
  nil
  [:a 'thingy map])

=> nil

Notice that + can't even be applied to any of [:a 'thingy map]. It isn't. To understand why not, you have to look at the way and works.
The expression (and m other-stuff) expands to (if m other-stuff m), which, if m is nil, returns nil. The other-stuff is never even evaluated.
Your failed reduces wrap this up in a couple of obfuscating layers.

You deal with two data at once, as values of the :min and :max
keys of a map.
A map returns nil as the value of an absent key.

Note
For simplicity, I've removed the way and avoids double evaluation of its arguments.
